# Can I add a calculated boolean column to an Elasticsearch Kibana query from data from another query?

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql, calculated-columns, calculated-field

Let's imagine that we have an Elastic index and we want to get all the documents of that index and a calculated field with the result of a filtering a different Elastic index.

I will better explain that in SQL code so even if Elastic is NoSQL, I can share the goal:

```
select id, name, (id IN (select customer_id from invoices where customer_id = 123)) as hasBought
from customers;
```

Comment: Are you only considering ES or have you already inserted some flattened docs into ES? In case of the latter, what do they look like? Can you share some sample docs?

Comment: Yes, we have ES already implemented with some indexes filled with flattened docs. Picture those flats as replicas of SQL tables. One workaround could be to duplicate those "foreign id's" from one index in the other index as a nested field. But I wonder if we can avoid this duplication in maintenance every create, update & delete operation (and in space). Elastic has the data and would do that much faster than the backend.

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch doesn't support table joining. You'll need to denormalize your data one way or another, even it results in data duplication. That's the "downside" of NoSQL like ES.

Quoting the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html):

> Performing full SQL-style joins in a distributed system like Elasticsearch is prohibitively expensive. Instead, Elasticsearch offers two forms of join which are designed to scale horizontally.